# Lifting ${\rm SO}(D)$ to ${\rm Spin}(D)$ smoothly

Tags: analysis, differential-topology, lie-groups

I have a question about a very basic thing. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and suppose that we have a smooth map $g:M\to {\rm SO}(D)$. Let $\rho : {\rm Spin}(D)\to {\rm SO}(D)$ be the covering map. Since $\ker \rho = \{\pm 1\}$ at each $x\in M$ the equation $$\rho(\tilde{g}(x))=g(x)\tag{1}$$

has two solutions. So choosing one solution at each $x\in M$ this defines a function $\tilde{g}:M\to {\rm Spin}(D)$. Intuitively it is very clear to me that we can choose the solutions so that $\tilde{g}$ is smooth as well, but I fail to see how to prove it. I mean this is something that is probably *extremely basic*, but I'm really missing it. So how could we argue that it is always possible to pick the solutions of (1) at each $x\in M$ such that the resulting function $\tilde{g}$ is smooth?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to choose a continuous lift $\tilde g$ *locally*, but it may not be possible to do so *globally*.

As a simpler counterexample, consider the circle $S^1$ as the set of unit complex numbers $e^{i\theta}\in\mathbb{C}$. The map $c(z)=z^2$ is a double covering map $S^1\to S^1$. The identity $\operatorname{id}:S^1\to S^1$ is of course continuous, but there is no continuous map $f:S^1\to S^1$ such that $c\circ f=\operatorname{id}$. This can be proven using fundamental groups.

The same is true in your case. If we take $M=S^1$ and choose a map $g:S^1\to SO(D)$ which is not homotopic to a constant map, then there will be no continuous lift $\tilde{g}$ satisfying $\rho\circ\tilde{g}=g$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kajelad ! I think that choosing the lift to be continuous locally would already suffice. I'm interested in the subject because of the construction of spin structures. In that case, given the principal ${\rm SO}(D)$ bundle of orthonormal frames over some oriented Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, if $\Omega_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j:\to {\rm SO}(D)$ are the transition maps of the bundle defined in overlaps between trivializing open subsets we would need to lift those $\Omega_{ij}$ to $\widetilde{\Omega}_{ij}$. I take that such a lift (which is local) would then be possible right?

Comment: By locally, I mean there is an open set $U$ around each point so that $g|_U$ has a lift; it may or may not be possible to stitch these local lifts together continuously. This isn't sufficient for what you're trying to do: It may not be possible to lift the transition functions on $U_i\cap U_j$, and even if it is, it may not be possible to choose lifts that result in a well-defined principal $\operatorname{Spin}(D)$-bundle. Indeed, there are some oriented Riemannian manifolds which do not admit spin structures.